# Dollars to Kids

Tags: logical-deduction

Daam has 8 children, named Esha, Hansika, Deepa, Rinsu, Ira, Vimky, Abhiteet and Aankhal. She has 36 dollars with her. One day, she gifted the dollars among her children such that the eldest child got 8 dollars, the second eldest child got 7 dollars and so on and the youngest child got 1 coin. After getting the dollars, the 8 children played a game, in which each of them got different ranks. The winner in the game got 8 dollars from the eldest child, the first runner up got 7 dollars from the second eldest child and so on.

For every child:

a. Gain in the game = The number of dollars with him/her after the game is over – The number of dollars gifted to him/her by mother 
b. Loss in the game = The number of dollars gifted to him/her by mother – The number of dollars with him/her after the game is over

Following points are known:

> 1. Vimky is not the eldest one and he did not win the game.
> 2. The number of dollars gifted to Deepa by her mother was a composite number. The number of dollars she had after the game was a prime
>      number.
> 3. The mother gifted dollars equal to the number of letters in the name of only one child.
> 4. The number of dollars gifted by the mother to Rinsu was more than exactly 5 other children. She was the only one who did not have either
>      gain or loss in the game.
> 5. Ira lost 4 dollars in the game, which was more than the loss suffered by any other child. Further, Ira did not get 7 dollars from
>      her mother.
> 6. Aankhal and Abhiteet had consecutive number of dollars both before and after the game, such that Aankhal got fewer dollars than Abhiteet
>      both before and after the game.
> 7. Hansika gained more dollars in the game than any other child.
> 8. Esha did not suffer a loss in the game.
> 9. Vimky did not get 5 dollars from his mother.

Please tell the approach. 
**PS : It can't be solved completely.**

Comment: Can this one be solved completely?

Comment: "the eldest child got 8 dollars, the second eldest child got 7 dollars and so on and the youngest child got 1 coin"- is a coin equal to a dollar in this problem?

Comment: Are you the creator of this puzzle or did you find it somewhere else? If it's the latter, please add your source!

Comment: @Greg It cant be solved completely.

Comment: @sam.  You need to start making completely solvable puzzles.  (Or, at the very least, say that it can't be completely solved).  Otherwise I am wasting my time and am less likely to do your puzzles in the future.

Comment: -1 as it can't be solved completely. Always make sure to post solvable puzzles, or as @Greg points out, we're wasting our time.

Comment: Maybe in the future you could add a line in the puzzle saying 'solve or prove that it cannot be completely solved' so people know there is a chance it is unsolvable and only those who are willing to try and solve a possibly unsolvable puzzle will try the question. I think it may help with the overall reception of your puzzles.

Comment: I will take care to mention it in future. I am sorry if it wasted your time.

Comment: I enjoy the puzzles, but I spent a lot of time trying to figure out the last clue.  A heads up that I **can't** solve it would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this may be a little unclear, so assuming I am correct in everything this is what I have so far:

Note: Phase 1 (p1) is after mother distributes, phase 2 (p2) is after the game. (#) denotes the clue I used to figure it out.

> (1) Vimky does not have 8 dollars p1 or p2.
> (2) Deepa has 8, 6, 4, or 1 dollars p1, 7, 5, 3, 2, or 1 p2.
> (4) Rinsu has 6 dollars p1 and p2.
> (5) Ira has 8, or 5 p1, and 4 or 1 p2.
> (6) Aankhal does not have 8 or 5 p1 or p2.  Abhiteet does not have 7 p1 or p2
> (7) Hansika has to gain at least 2 from p1->p2, so they do not have 8 or 7 p1
> (3) Esha (the only one left with this possibility) has 4 p1 and can only have 8, 7 or 5 p2.
> Deepa has 8 p1, Ira has 5 p1 and 1 p2.
> Aankhal does not have 7 and Abhiteet does not have 8 or 5 p1 or p2.
>  
> Aankhal has 2 or 1 p1, 3 or 2 p2.  Abhiteet has 3 or 2 p1 and 4 or 3 p1.
> (5) Vimky is the only one option for 7 p1 and can lose a max of 3, so has 5 or 4 p2.  Deepa, similarly, can only have 7 or 5 p2.
> (7)Hamsika cannot have 2 p2.
> So Aankhal has 2 p2, 1 p1.
> Abhiteet has 3 p1, 4 p2.
> Hansika has 3 p1 and 8, 7, 5 p2.
> Vimky has 4 p2.
> Hamsika cannot have 5 p2 otherwise, Esha gained more.  Esha cannot gain 8 or Hamsika **tied** Esha for total gain, so Hamsika has 8 p2.

Trying to figure out the missing part, but so far (8->1):

> p1: Deepa, Vimsky, Rinsu, Ira, Esha, Hamsika, Abhiteet, Aankhal
> p2: Hamsika, Esha/Deepa, Rinsu, Esha/Deepa, Vimky, Abhiteet, Aankhal, Ira

Update: I think this is as far as I can get with the hints.  Feel free to let me know if 1) I messed something up (definitely possible) and 2) if there's any insight into what I'm missing.

Comment: I don't think the children have to have 1-8 dollars after the game. Please correct me if I'm mistaken.

Comment: Wait, they do. Never mind.

Comment: Like I said, I think this is a little unclear.  I interpreted it to mean the winner just ended up with 8 dollars, the loser 1

Comment: Yeah, I think that's how it works.

Comment: @ExcitedRaichu ok cool. if it's not how it works, I don't see how it's at all possible

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty sure this is as far as we can go. I rechecked this with all the hints and there's no way to determine the difference.

Comment: It cant be solved completely.

Comment: @ExcitedRaichu that's annoying.

Comment: sam, am I correct then?

Comment: Yes you are correct @Greg.Thanks for solving it. I apologize again for the incovenience caused. You can be sure that i will take care to point out if the puzzle is unsolvable.

Comment: No problem!  I look forward to the next one!